# Getting database creation error in Neo4j- Mac mojave

Tags: neo4j, macos-mojave

Following is the error:

> Database failed to create: Error: The username or passphrase you entered is not correct.

I tried all the possible solutions that I could find on the internet:

- deleted the neo4j completely and reinstalled.
- completely removed /Library/Application Support/Neo4j Desktop
- tried with both java 8 and java 11

Also, I'm not able to connect to any remote database.  Nothing seems to be working.
It would be really helpful if somebody provides me with the solution

[image: screenshot]